# Flutter : check if there's specific data in the subcollection

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating a post that uploads data to Firestore's sub-collection and brings it up to MyBookmark page.   It's good to create a sub-collection and upload data simply.  And now I'd like to add a 'data duplication prevention' function here.
If the post is already saved in the bookmark, should not upload it.

For this purpose, I would like to check if the post is already in the collection when I press the bookmark button.

```
        IconButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            //get userModel
            UserModelState _userModelstate =
                Provider.of<UserModelState>(context, listen: false);

            //=========================================
            //duplication data test
            DocumentReference bookmarkRef = Firestore.instance
                .collection(COLLECTION_USERS)
                .document(_userModelstate.userModel.userKey)
                .collection(COLLECTION_BOOKMARk)
                // .where(KEY_BOOKMARK_PRODUCTKEY, isEqualTo: productKey)
                .document();

            DocumentSnapshot bookmarkSnapshot = await bookmarkRef.get();

            //test (return "No exist")
            if(bookmarkSnapshot.exists) {
              print("Yes exist");
            } else {
              print("No exist");
            }
```

[image]

I tried writing a code to check if there was data in the collection, but it is always printed as "No exist".
How can I confirm the existence of a specific document in collection?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `productKey` is supposed to be unique in the `Bookmark` collection of the user, consider using the `productKey` as the document ID. Since document IDs are by definition unique within their collection, using them guarantees unique product keys without you having to write any code for it.

---

That said, you current code can't work because you call `document()`. Whenever you call `document()` without any parameters, it generates a reference to a new unique document. And since you immediately call `get()` on that reference, the document will (also: by definition) not exist yet.

To check if a document with a specific product ID exist, you will need to run a query:

```
CollectionReference bookmarksRef = Firestore.instance
    .collection(COLLECTION_USERS)
    .document(_userModelstate.userModel.userKey)
    .collection(COLLECTION_BOOKMARk);
Query bookmarkQuery = bookmarksRef.where(KEY_BOOKMARK_PRODUCTKEY, isEqualTo: productKey);

QuerySnapshot bookmarkSnapshot = await bookmarkQuery.get();

if (bookmarkSnapshot.size > 0) {
  print("product key already in use");
}
```